# Google Cloud Mysql not get connected from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

My App is hosted in google app engine flex environment and i have a database which hosted in cloud sql (Mysql) 2nd generation instance. but both are different project . I given the permission also.

I am getting "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" error

Can any one help me ?

Thanks,
Subash

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your app is written in PHP: to connect to a Cloud SQL instance one uses a Unix socket and an extension such as  mysql and mysqli, both [enabled by default](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#PHP_Enabled_extensions) in the PHP runtime for App Engine.  You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554143/connection-issue-connecting-from-php-app-engine-instance-to-a-cloud-sql-instance) a good example of connecting using mysqli_connect.  The attention in this case has to be focused on the use of the socket argument in the mysqli_connect() call.

The PHP team generally [recommends using PDO or mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), not the original mysql.

More detail is needed to set the basis of an effective investigation in your issue. Any information you deem relevant might prove invaluable.

One can use a PDO object only after creating it with a ["new" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework).

Comment: This is not the answer for this. just want to know any additional settings is required to connect cloud sql from app engine

Comment: I got answer.. Only from std environment it will work